# Programmatically add Views inside a (Linear)Layout (that is inside a ScrollView)

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, scrollview, layout-inflater

I have an app that, after some clicking, shows activity with news contents. I want at a bottom of that to show comments, which are dynamically loaded in async task.

One approach is to use ListView and custom ArrayAdapter, but, i would have to put ListView inside a ScrollView, and it is is a problem, even if i manually override ListView's height. It shows one list item, and one part of the following one.

The other approach is to define LinearLayout as a holder for comments, than inflate another LinearLayouts defined in it's own xml file, populate it's contents, attach to holder's view. It works fine, from program's point of view, except it pushes comments below contents of the news. It's like, it creates another scrollable view of comments underneath contents od news (contents overlap it).

Is there any other way of doing this that has nothing to do with lists, or how can i make the other approach to work.

The relevant code snippet from xml layout that holds news contents is:

```
<LinearLayout> //global layout
    <LinearLayout>
        //views that hold title, date, content
    </LinearLayout>      

        <LinearLayout 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/commentsHolder"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#ed1b24"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="KOMENTARI"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ed1b24"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/comments_holder_view"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and code that corresponds to one comment is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/comments_holder_item"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/comment_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/comments_back_details"
    android:text="Ovde ide tekst komentara, koji se, naravno, dinamicki dodaje."/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/comment_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/categoryStyle"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" | "
        style="@style/categoryStyle"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/comment_pubdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/categoryStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#d1d1d1">
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you very much for any reply. This is quite important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very sure how you inflate your `comments`, but here is how I would do it.

Declare the comments `Layout` as a `LinearLayout` and give it an id, and then get a reference to that `LinearLayout` :

```
LinearLayout commentsLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.commentsLayoutId);
```

and then just add child `Views` to this layout :

```
commentsLayout.addView(newComment);
```

Comment: usually you'll use `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.comment, null);` from your activity

Comment: I did exactly like you posted Ovidiu, it works fine, but somehow, that linear layout (with id comments_holder_view) that holds comments is lying under other layouts. If i include several comment layouts statically (manually) everything is displayed fine. It seems that the problem appears when dynamically add those views. Thanx for reply, though.

Comment: please post some code of how you are creating the views that are added (comments)?

Comment: @Ovidiu : view = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.comments_holder_view); LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);LinearLayout comm = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_item, null); view.addView(comm);

Comment: I still can't exactly understand, what doesn't look ok when adding them programatically....

Comment: Well, if you look at first code snippet, before LinLay (id=comments_holder_view) i have several Layouts and Views (Text, Image, etc). Forgotten to mention that code above is wrapped with ScrollView. So, when i insert comments where i want them, they are displayed, but news contents (mentioned Layouts and Views) overlap them. for example, if i have shorter news, that would take 1/2 of the screen, then those comments appear till the end of a screen. But if news is longer, i can see everything till comments holder (LL id=comments_holder_view).