# Scrollview doesn't scroll with 2 listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, scrollview

i search lot of topic about scrollview which doesn't scroll but no one can resolve my issue :/
if someone could help me :)
each listview print some people when i do a request from my server
normally  when i scroll down of my list the second list appear but it does not

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_for_background_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_for_background_white"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutScrollResult"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_for_background_white">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <com.whask.whask.utils.font.FontTextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_hot"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="5 HOT"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
                            app:font="Neo-Sans-Std-Medium.otf"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/result_whask_listview_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/layout2">
                    </ListView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/result_whask_listview_view"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <com.whask.whask.utils.font.FontTextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_not"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="2 NOT"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
                            app:font="Neo-Sans-Std-Medium.otf"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/result_whask_listview_view_no"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/layout3"
                        android:background="@color/my_whask_white_color">
                    </ListView>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should not use scrollview with listview as listview has it's own scrolling. Instead of using listview inflate your items in linear or frame layout. In this way you can easily achieve wrap content feature as listview doesn't work properly with wrap content

Comment: do you want to scroll listview inside scrollview ? @Mavrick Rmx

Comment: if i dont use ScrollView, my 2 FontTextView will not scroll and my second listview stay at the bottom and i can't see these elements, i need that my FontTextView scroll too @VivekMishra

Comment: I am not saying you should not use scrollview. I am saying not to use listview inside scrollview.

Comment: yes this is what i want, then my listView which are at bottom of my screen can replace the first listview @Rushabh042

Comment: Check my answer that way you can scroll listview and scrollview properly its working for me @MavrickRmx

Comment: you should replace both of your listview with dynamically inflated views inside a linear layout as a container for them

Comment: well i can't imagine how i can scroll all my view and display list of people whithout using listview inside scrollview :/ @VivekMishra

Comment: have you check my answer ? @MavrickRmx

Comment: then imagine it by searching how to inflate linear layout dynamically. This link can help you to imagine that way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908883/programmatically-add-views-inside-a-linearlayout-that-is-inside-a-scrollview

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT** use `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. `ListView` itself has a scroll property and you don't have to use another `ScrollView` to make it scroll. Use a `LinearLayout` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Listview have own scrolling property ,so dont use within scrollview...
    thanks